# GWT and Google Chrome Frame Bug: "compile time user.agent value does not match runtime user.agent value"

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-frame

I have a GWT 2.4.0 website hosted in Jetty. When I browse this website using IE8 I get the following alert message:

> ERROR: Possible problem with your *.gwt.xmi module file. 
>   The compile time user.agent value (ie8) does not match the runtime user.agent
>   value (safari). Expect more errors.

Why does GWT think my runtime user agent is Safari? How can I let it know it's actually IE8? Am I right in suspecting that having the Chrome Frame plug-in installed in my IE8 has something to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your *gwt.xml files.   Does it have something that looks like this:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

That's telling it to only compile the safari version.

Answer (score 0):

When GWT module is compiled with only one `user.agent` it doesn't check it in the bootstrap javascript, but loads directly that version. When that version checks the user.agent it finds (I guess) your Chrome frame and complains about its safari.

So... I guess you have only compiled your module with:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8">
```

I should either check how ChromeFrame vs. GWT behaviour is... or simply add both user.agents and let module bootstrap load what's correct for your runtime environment.

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,safari">
```

And of course I should check your ChromeFrame configuration to see what pages are loaded with it: all, none, some URLs, etc...